# Magento : Admin Page No Display

Tags: magento, admin

I need some help, how can I debugged this, since it has no display. How can I see the error of it? Thank You!

Comment: Can u describe more??, and for any error u can check error log in magento/var/report/ and check system.log and exception.log files.

Comment: it has tabs like Dashboards but below of it there is no content it just plain white. - sorry i tent to image of it. but it says must have 10 rep so i cant post sad to say.

Comment: i found error reporting sir. and this is the result..

Fatal error: Call to undefined function crypt_random_string() in /var/www/vhosts/96j.de/mistergrip/lib/Customweb/Licensing/SaferpayCw/Key.php(21) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : runtime-created function(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(22) : eval()'d code on line 88

Comment: remove cache and session folder data.

Comment: @ravipatel i already did that sir

Comment: your page not display can u define after login or before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try solving the problem using the below given link:

https://kb.magenting.com/content/22/38/en/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this.html

You might get better view of the error that occuring.

Comment: i found error reporting sir. and this is the result..

Fatal error: Call to undefined function crypt_random_string() in /var/www/vhosts/96j.de/mistergrip/lib/Customweb/Licensing/SaferpayCw/Key.php(21) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : runtime-created function(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(22) : eval()'d code on line 88

Comment: open up php.ini and allow the php_mycrypt.dll extension by removing the ;, i.e. changing:

;extension=php_mcrypt.dll to extension=php_mcrypt.dll

Comment: i aleady did that and thats the output.

Comment: i cant find extension=php_mcrypt.dll sir. im using ubuntu.

Comment: ok then use the following 
$ sudo mv /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
$ sudo php5enmod mcrypt
$ sudo service apache2 restart